# Where can I find "Use Nodes" checkbox for Light objects in Shader Editor?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, objects, lighting, shader-nodes

I'm using Blender 3.3 and I can't find the *Use Nodes* checkbox for Light objects in Cycles. Where do I find this checkbox in Cycles?

Answer (score 1):

It should be under the light properties (with the light selected):

[image: Light]

It can also be accessed from the shading tab (also with the light selected):

[image: Light2]

If your settings do not look like this, something may be wrong with your blender setup. Start with factory settings if necessary